# How to deal with new lines in encryption algorithm?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, powershell, encryption, scripting

I am converting an ASP encryption algorithm (used in one of my applications) to PowerShell in order to encrypt a set of 100 random strings. When studying the output of my script, I see that there are ~120 lines of text produced. The original application inserts the encrypted strings into an SQL database. I will be manually adding my encrypted strings to the same database.

**Q:** Is my algorithm introducing new line characters? Why am I receving more than 100 lines of output? Can these encrypted strings still be added to an SQL database?

**Original ASP Function:**

```
Function Encrypt(pwd)
    Dim key
    key = "_-#{[}]|!`~>(-<+"

    Dim strRet
    Dim nStrLen
    nStrLen = Len(pwd)
    Dim n
    For n = 1 To nStrLen
        strRet = strRet & Chr(Asc(Mid(pwd, n, 1)) Xor Asc(Mid(key, n, 1)))
    Next

    Encrypt = strRet
End Function
```

**My PowerShell implementation:**

```
function Encrypt ([string]$unencryptedPassword)
{
    $key = "_-#{[}]|!`~>(-<+";
    $nStrLen = $unencryptedPassword.length;

    For ($n=0; $n -lt $nStrLen; $n++)
        {
            $tmpPWD = $unencryptedPassword.substring($n,1);
            $tmpKEY = $key.substring($n,1);

            $tmpPWD = [byte][char]$tmpPWD;
            $tmpKEY = [byte][char]$tmpKEY;

            $tmpResult = $tmpResult + [char]($tmpPWD -bxor $tmpKEY);
        }

    return $tmpResult;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please ask if more information is required.

Comment: This "encryption" algorithm appears to merely XOR plaintext with the key. This provides no real protection at all. Do you have to port this over or can you swap it out with code that actually works?

Comment: Also, in VBScript the `Mid` function uses `1` as the first character, but .NET (and so PowerShell) uses `0` as the first character, so you've got a bunch of bugs coming from that alone.

Comment: @Dai I have to use this algorithm. Typically the application in which the algorithm is used allows the addition of one string to our database at a time. I want to recreate the algorithm in PowerShell so I can bulk create 100 strings and manually add them to the database.

Comment: @Dai I am using the `substring` function to get the same functionality as `Mid`. I start at index 1 rather than 0. Does this not handle the issue you mentioned?

Comment: No, it doesn't, you need to start from `0`, not `1`, that's my point.

Comment: I have updated my code based off your observation. Thanks @Dai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my algorithm introducing new line characters?

Your algorithm produces *bytes*.  It's entirely possible that some of those bytes represent ASCII newline or other control characters.  Whether or not you can "manually" insert those into SQL depends on how you do that.

Comment: Is their a file format in which ASCII characters can be viewed/manipulated with out them producing their intended output (in this case a new line)? I would want to insert these strings via SQL queries. Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: The problem is you have to be able to separate each "string".  You can encode the strings in base-64 so that no control characters are possible but then you have to decode it before storing in in SQL (or store it encoded and decode it when you extract it).

Comment: I have to utilize the same encryption algorithm because these strings will later be decrypted by an equivalent decryption function used in the same program.

Comment: You can keep the same algorithm but encode the results so that they can be safely stored as ASCII.  You won't be able to "paste" in into a SQL query though.  You'll need to write a program to decode it and store it.

Comment: @DStanley T-SQL (as used by SQL Server) does support binary literals. Use `0x` as a prefix to a hexadecimal string.

Comment: @Dai True but you'd have to store it in the text file as a hexadecimal string.  But that may be the bast choice here.